# ctrl+click in pydev for super

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I am trying to navigate code in pydev using ctrl+click. However in the following scenario, Ctrl+clicking "super(B, self).foo()" returns a list of files to choose from and ctrl+clicking "super(B, self).**init**()" just beeps. Should'nt pydev be able to follow the class hierarchy and go to the correct super class?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super(B, self).foo()
```

Comment: It seems PyDev isn't handling super() very well in that case... please create a feature request for that at: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev

Comment: As a note, this was improved for 5.6.0 (so, the next release should have that fixed).